# Consulta Modelo de Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, phpmyadmin

Hola todos tengo una consulta la cuestión es, tengo en la base de datos 3 tablas alumno, tutor y persona. Alumno tiene claves foráneas a persona y a tutor, mi duda es, tengo problemas al traer el nombre del tutor, necesito el nombre del alumno pero tambien el nombre del tutor que no me esta trayendo, esos datos están en la tabla persona les coloco la query que realizo me podrian ayudar Gracias!!.

```
$this->db->select('alumno.* , persona.name as alumnopersona_name,persona.dni as alumnopersona_dni,persona.cuil as persona_cuil ,curso.name as curso_name, estado_alumno.name as estadoalumno_name, escuela.name as escuela_name, tutor.persona_id as tutorpersona, persona.name as tutorpersona_name');
    $this->db->from('alumno');
    $this->db->join('persona', 'alumno.persona_id = persona.id', 'left');
    $this->db->join('tutor', 'alumno.tutor_id=tutor.id');                   
    $this->db->join('curso','alumno.curso_id= curso.id','left');
    $this->db->join('escuela','alumno.escuela_id= escuela.id','left');
    $query = $this->db->get();


     if ($query->num_rows()>0) {
         return $query->result();
     }else
     {
        return FALSE;
     }
```

Comment: En ningún lado mandas a llamar el nombre del tutor y en el select mandas a llamar `estado_alumno.name as estadoalumno_name` no se de donde... se mas especifico y muestra la estructura de tus tablas, iba a hacer una respuesta pero creo que para darte algo mas concreto es mejor que seas mas especifico y complementes tu pregunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$this->db->select(
'alumno.* , 
**persona.name as alumnopersona_name**,
persona.dni as alumnopersona_dni,persona.cuil as persona_cuil ,curso.name as curso_name, estado_alumno.name as estadoalumno_name, escuela.name as escuela_name, tutor.persona_id as tutorpersona, **persona.name as tutorpersona_name**');

Estás diciéndole que coja el campo **persona.name** 2 veces pero con alias distintos y solo te está extrayendo 1.

Lo mejor es que hagas una subconsulta para coger en nombre el tutor y del alumno por separado:

```
$this->db->select('alumno.* , SELECT (persona.name WHERE persona.id = alumno.id) as alumnopersona_name,persona.dni as alumnopersona_dni,persona.cuil as persona_cuil ,curso.name as curso_name, estado_alumno.name as estadoalumno_name, escuela.name as escuela_name, tutor.persona_id as tutorpersona, SELECT (persona.name WHERE persona.id = tutor.id) as tutorpersona_name');
$this->db->from('alumno');
$this->db->join('persona', 'alumno.persona_id = persona.id', 'left');
$this->db->join('tutor', 'alumno.tutor_id=tutor.id');                   
$this->db->join('curso','alumno.curso_id= curso.id','left');
$this->db->join('escuela','alumno.escuela_id= escuela.id','left');
```